# Why can tsconfig.json not find my files in a src folder?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I am giving my first try at TypeScript compiling and I am trying to do it within Visual Studio Code with a tsconfig file.

I have read the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) at the [TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org) site and believe I have formatted my file the correct way but the error I keep getting in the output is:

> error TS6053: File
>   'c:/Users/username/devbox/home/tsc-play/**/*.ts' not found.
>   2:46:11 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.

However, in that folder there is a 'hello.ts' file.

Here is the code for my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "outFile": "dist/bundle.js",
        "watch": true
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "files": [
        "src/*.ts"
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to change the "files" to "include" in your tsconfig file.

The `files` flag looks for specific files while `include` can use glob syntax.

Comment: To extend on this, `files` is an exact match where `include` is a glob like match.